# How to send email locally in .net core without credentials

Tags: iis, c#-4.0, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-8

I want to test sending emails in my web app which is using .net core 3 with C#.

The issue is I am on a corporate network which blocks port 587 (for now).

I saw an article which says you can use this

```
mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
```

But I am hosting with .net core which is not configured for IIS so I get an error "IIS delivery is not supported".

Is IIS the only way to test sending emails locally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the option `SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory`
The mail will be picked up from the directory specified in the property `SmtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation`

You can see the reference pages for:

- [SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpdeliverymethod?view=netcore-3.0)
- [SmtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.pickupdirectorylocation?view=netcore-3.0#System_Net_Mail_SmtpClient_PickupDirectoryLocation)

For example:

```
var client = new SmtpClient {
  DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory,
  PickupDirectoryLocation = @"c:\myMailFolder"
};
```

Comment: Although this answer is correct, the solution is not the most convenient since one needs to use an email app to open email file created by this option.

Comment: @Bronek this answer is incredibly convenient, and you can open the file with NotePad++ or other text editor.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know np++ can do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a moq (fake) SMTP server as part of your app. The emails won't be delivered to the recipients but stored in-memory so they can be inspected.

I'm the author of the [SmtpMoq.NET](https://github.com/StephanZahariev/SmtpMoq.NET) for .NET Core that does exactly that. Please check [here](https://github.com/StephanZahariev/SmtpMoq.NET) and [here](http://szahariev.blogspot.com/2020/01/introducing-smtpmoqnet.html) for details how to utilize it.

Additional benefit will be that you can automate your integration tests and verify if the emails are correctly sent.

Hope this helps.